# How to export report excel in website using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, excel, export

I want to export file to excel like this in my website. Is there any way to make it ? If can't do that with angularjs, please give me any suggestion(tool,lib or another languages can embedded to my website support this) to do that. Thanks.
This is file execel:
[image: picture file excel]

Answer (score 0):

In our team we had a similar issue and we searched a lot for solution, we didn't find any good tool for this task except for creating a simple csv file, so in the end we decided to do all the reporting (PDF, Excel ,...) in server side.

Comment: Thanks you very much.